# How to connect 2 office networks together with no router access

Tags: networking, remote-access, local-area-network, cloud, wide-area-network

We have two offices which have a server each and we want all relevant personnel in each office to access the work on each.

I don't have access to the router on my end because it's a communal router between all the offices in our building who are nothing to do with us.

In my office I have installed a Synology NAS and I think it's a windows server that's in the other office but I can find out for sure.

Our workers have access to the jobs on the Synology NAS which at the moment is syncing with google drive but this is causing problems because the workers are also linked to the google drive through the drive app on their individual PC's and it's comparing and syncing all the time, I think duplicate are being made i.e. fileName(1) are appearing.

Can we create a link between the 2 servers using VPN or something, or should I go for the cloud option? At the moment it's Google Drive but would Amazon or something else be better?

Comment: *I don't have access to the router on my end because it's a communal router* ... Do you mean to say you're sharing a LAN with other users who have nothing to do with your organization? That's a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: The router is like a hub which serves the whole building. So each office doesn't have an individual router. We had these but they were taken out a couple of months ago, therefore no single business can access the router or edit it to suit their needs.

Comment: While I acknowledge the difficulty created by not being able to configure the router, the problem I'm pointing out is that it sounds like all of the systems inside the building are on the same network...and therefore if poor security practices in Business A lead to their computers getting infected with a virus, there's little to prevent Business B, C, and Z from getting attacked too.  That's a serious security problem.

Comment: @twisty yeah,  I said this to them at the time of the upgrade but they explained that it wouldn't be an issue and they knew what they were doing. They took down the router we had and extracted switches that I had put in.

Comment: Unless you trust (i.e. have complete control over) the other systems on the network, this is a very dangerous configuration. Suppose something even slightly confidential is stored anywhere on one of your computers. A easy way to gain unauthorized access to your data is through one of these other systems. You would do well to put a router between your own computers and the rest of the network...assuming you can connect all your computers to that router or switches connected to the private side of that router.

Comment: @twisty, its not allowed. Its a govt. Building and they assure me that each office is isolated.

Comment: I hope they're correct. Good luck getting your locations connected.

Comment: @Paul66 Given it is government buildings, the group that replaced the routers should be able to configure the required connections securely.  Contact them with your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go for the cloud option. And you should create a VPN. And so something else.

All depends really.

- How critical is the data? If someone leaks it, is it a problem?
- Can you cope with disconnections? From each other? From the data?
- etc...?

Have a think about what you need from this solution and then think about whether a design you come up with meets the requirements.

If you're quite happy that either office can have no access to their documents for a day or 2 while BT put a backhoe through the fibre (been there...) then put it on a Cloud provider (Box, Amazon Workdocs, Google Drive, etc...).

Or, do you have 2 offices of hundreds of people that can do no work if the one router that you don't manage and has no resilience goes down. That's the sort of mistake that can sink a small business. Nobody getting any work done for 2 days because all the data is in the cloud (or the other office). In which case, you probably need your current solution with a local storage for day to day work and a VPN between them so each office can access the other occasionally.

If your data is in a cloud, do you need an SSO solution? Or are you happy that people have a username and password that they remembered? (Pa55word probably). That may influence your choice of cloud provider, some may allow integration with your internal auth system, some not. (SSO can remove the need for them to login, the files are just "there" when they want them, which is great if your users are non-technical.)

Create some free accounts with providers, load in a few documents, share them with people, ask them to do that same, take a survey "how easy was it to use?" "How easy was it to get your job done?" (those 2 aren't necessarily the same, something can be very easy to use but a PITA for me to make useful for work) and other questions.

Comment: The data isn't critical and both offices don't need access all the time. The cloud option is my preferred choice too and I can keep the has going for our office man, but can be accessed by other office to view and discuss data from time to time. I would also links the VPN to be used occasionally also. So, what cloud service would be best, we have Google just now but I'm having issues with it. I have a synology nas here but the other office doesn't have a nas. Is openVPN a good option? I have some network skills but haven't set up a VPN before.

Comment: Sorry, The above comment there is gobbledygook, I was typing it on my pad last night and autocorrect was changing everything!!

The data isn't critical and both offices don't need access all the time. 

The cloud option is my preferred choice too and I can keep the NAS going for our LAN in my office, but also so it can be accessed by the other office to view and discuss data from time to time (we work with architectural drawings). I would also like the VPN to be used occasionally also.

Comment: So, what cloud service would be best, we have Google Drive just now but I'm having issues with it. I have a Synology NAS here but the other office doesn't have a nas. Is openVPN a good option? I have some network skills but haven't set up a VPN before. Any good tutorials?

Comment: I'm liking the look of Amazon Workdocs these days.
It has good features. Sync clients for many platforms, AD integration, IAM integration.
But like I say, get some trials going and test out various providers, see which one is right for you.

OpenVPN is good and free. But unless you get their paid product, you'd better be a command line guru. openssl commands must be second nature!
https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/88-1xhowto.html
Takes you through a peer to peer connection. Written for version1 but still appropriate for v2.

Comment: Thanks, good to know, I'm ok with command line but no guru by any means. Looking at the tutorial link you gave me I understand most of the commands and will have a try, but if it all goes wrong i'll jump ship. 

Will source out other VPN tools and communicate with the technician at the other end of this of our network to see what he can come up with. The Synology NAS has a cloud station plugin so I may be able to use that for the cloud.

Thanks for everyone's help and if you can think of anything else, please add.